# On what branch does Meta Stack Overflow run?

Tags: discussion

I know it's not identical to Stack Overflow, because at least one feature exists in SO but not in meta-SO: Clicking the total number of votes on a questions splits into positive and negative votes on SO, but not on meta-SO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will once you have 1,000 reputation.

If you read the [FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq), that ability only is granted after you have 1,000 reputation.

Comment: Thanks. And now, for the followup: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/46282/why-does-it-take-1000-rep-to-show-the-total-up-down-vote-counts

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the lower right-hand corner of the page, you can see the actual svn revision number.

Right now, they're both at the same revision (6801).

Comment: but are they a different branch hmmm..

Comment: No, they are probably the same branch with differing configs...